# how to change the rootviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I want to change the rootViewController after the authenticationViewController [image]

```
-(IBAction)LoginButtonPushed:(id)sender {
    if ([(VerifyId)isEqual:@"C"]){
        CondidatsViewController *condidatsViewController = [[[CondidatsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CondidatsViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
        UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;

        NSMutableArray *controllers = [[self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy] autorelease];
        [controllers removeLastObject];
        navController.viewControllers = controllers;
        [navController pushViewController:condidatsViewController animated: YES];

    } else {
        RecruteursViewController *recruteursViewController = [[[RecruteursViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RecruteursViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
        UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;

        NSMutableArray *controllers = [[self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy] autorelease];
        [controllers removeLastObject];
        navController.viewControllers = controllers;
        [navController pushViewController:recruteursViewController animated: YES];
    }
}
```

this code is when i press in login button i want CondidatsViewController or RecruteursViewController will be the rootView

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    AcceuilViewController *viewController =[[[AcceuilViewController alloc]
                                             initWithNibName:@"AcceuilViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
    self.navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController]
                         autorelease];
   self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try UINavigationController's following method with a new array of desired view controllers something like

```
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[newRootViewControllerInstance, secondVCInstanceIfRequired, thirdVC-and-so-on....] animated:NO];
```

It will do the trick ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about have a view controller one level above your nav and auth view controllers?  This view controller can check for a valid session and push whatever view is appropriate on top of the stack.  It seems ill advised to try to change your root view controller.

## Edit: More details

You have a root view controller that doesn't have a view tied to it like most other view controllers might.  You set this class as the root view controller in your app delegate.

App Delegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    
    
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    return YES;
}
```

In your root view controller you can determine if you have a valid session or not.  Based on that, you can render the appropriate view.

RootViewController.m

```
@interface RootViewController ()
@end

@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    BOOL isUserAuthenticated = [MyClasskToFigureOutIfUserIsAuthenticated isUserAuthenticated];

    if(isUserAuthenticated == NO) {
        AuthViewController *vcAuth = [[AuthViewController alloc] init];
        [self addChildViewController:vcAuth];
        [self.view addSubView:vcAuth.view];
    } else {
        //they are authenticated so push your other view controller.
    }
}

@end
```

This is pretty rough, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: can you explain more please ?