# How to set the view controller as root view controller in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have one view controller with out navigation controller. Its name is `LoginViewController`. In my `AppDelegate`, I want to keep my `LoginViewController` as root view controller.

How can I do this in Objective-C? How can I set my view controller as root view controller?

Note: My view controller does not have navigation view controller. It's a single view controller.

Comment: are you uisng storyboard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change RootViewController in AppDelegate From Other ViewController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17408171/how-to-change-rootviewcontroller-in-appdelegate-from-other-viewcontroller)

Comment: Yes i am using storyboard

Answer (score 2):

do like

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// 1. get the Storyboard Name
UIStoryboard* main = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                               bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
//2. get the ViewController using Storyboard ID
UIViewController *viewConr = [main instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"]; 
// 3.finally assign the Root
self.window.rootViewController = viewConr;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

for E.g

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Without storyboard:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    LoginViewcontroller *Vc = [[LoginViewcontroller alloc]init];
    self.window.rootViewController = Vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**If using storyboard just make that view controller as initial view controller from storyboard.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set home page VC as root vc from login page VC

Import appdelegate in login page

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"//Import in Login page VC
self.delegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; // In viewDidLoad
```

Write below code where you navigate

```
//Make root view controller
UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
HomeViewController * hvc = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];//Your Home page story board ID
self.delegate.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:hvc];
[self.delegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```